# after edit the quantity is not increasing from stocks as well as not decreasing

Tags: python, django, crud

Now quantity of product is updating correctly but when I edit the data the quantity is not updating it is not decreasing as well as not increasing in the database, I want when I edit a data if the quantity is more than before the difference between old quantity and new quantity will be added and if the difference between old and new quantity is less than it will be decreased ...

Please Help me in that

models.py

```
# models.py
from collections.abc import Collection
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def clean_mobile(self):
        mobile=self.mobile
        if len(str(mobile))!= 10:
            raise ValidationError("invalid mobile number")
        return mobile


class Supplier(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, 
    decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
    quantity= models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    category=models.CharField(choices=CHOICES3,max_length=10)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name

CHOICES3 = [('Tshirt','Tshirt'),('Jeans','Jeans'),('Jacket','Jacket'),('Shoes','Shoes'),('Watch','Watch')]
CHOICES2 = [('Polo-Tshirt','Polo-Tshirt'),('Levis-Jeans','Levis-Jeans'),('Denim-Jacket','Denim-Jacket'),('Puma-Shoes','Puma-Shoes'),('Titan-Watch','Titan-Watch')]


class Stocks(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES2,max_length=100)
    quantity = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=100)


    def __str__(self):
         return self.product_name
```

views.py

```
def supplier_dashboard(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_name = request.POST.get('product_name')
        product_price = request.POST.get('product_price')
        image = request.FILES.get('image')
        quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
        category = request.POST.get('category')
        data = Supplier.objects.create(user=request.user, category=category, product_name=product_name, product_price=product_price, image=image, quantity=quantity)
        data.save()
        supplier = Supplier.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update_stocks', args=[data.id]))
    else:
        supplier = Supplier.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'enroll/supplier_dashboard.html', {'suppliers': supplier})
```

supplier_edit.view

```
def supplier_edit(request,id):
    try:
        product=Supplier.objects.get(id=id)
        if product.user == request.user:
            if request.method=='POST':
                    product.product_name = request.POST.get('product_name')
                    product.product_price = request.POST.get('product_price')
                    if 'image' in request.FILES:
                        product.image=request.FILES.get('image')
                    product.quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
                    product.category = request.POST.get('category')
                    product.save()
                    messages.success(request,"ProDuct Updated Succesfully")
                    return redirect('supplier_dashboard')
            return render(request,'enroll/supplier_edit.html',{'products':product})
    except Exception as e :
        messages.error(request," Some Error Occured ",e)     
        return render(request,'enroll/supplier_edit.html',{'products':product})

def update_stocks(request, id):
    print("------------", id)
    product = Supplier.objects.get(id=id)
    stocks = Stocks.objects.get(product_name=product.product_name)
    print(product.quantity, stocks.quantity)
    stocks.quantity = stocks.quantity - product.quantity
    stocks.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('supplier_dashboard'))
```

Comment: maybe first add `quantity` to database. And later show code.

Comment: okay added quantity to the database

Comment: as for me you should first create `class Stock`  with total `quantity` (and `name`, etc.)- and when you create new `Supplier` then you should `Stock.quantity -= Supplier.quantity`. First it needs to filter `Stock` using the same `product.product_name` (and mayb other values), and next you can subtract, and finally `save()`

Comment: can you please show me how can I do that just do it for a product like t-shirt and please make a view and model according to that, I will do it further ?

Comment: can you guys please see this now old error was solved i just got a new one please go with the code once more !

Comment: theoretically if you have new problem then you should create new question on new page.

Comment: I would run `update_stocks()` directly in  `supplier_edit()` in `if request.method=='POST:` without redirections.

Comment: 'redirect` always sends request as `GET`, never `POST` but you expect `POST` inside `update_stocks()` - and I wouldn't use `redirect` for this because it is only waste of time,

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing. Especially check `request.method` in `supplier_dashboard`